# SQL: Query column (string) as date

Tags: sql, sqlite

Assume I have a few columns in a database: `id`, `date_added`, `tag`

```
`20134` | `February 07, 2019` | `New`
`40323` | `February 09, 2019` | `New`
```

I want to run a query with a filter based on `date_added`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date_added > 'February 08, 2019'
```

How would I do this? I saw you can convert strings to date objects, but wasn't sure if that is possible inside a `WHERE` filter.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I am using SQLite

Comment: Yes you can easily do that in the WHERE clause, how depends on what database you are using. Please tag your question with the correct DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose a format for the `date_added` column, that is not comparable. 
SQLite is not that flexible with dates, which are in fact `Text`. 
So in this case you need to extract the date parts piece by piece and create a comparable date:

```
select *
from tablename
where 
  substr(date_added, instr(date_added, ',') + 2) ||
  case substr(date_added, 1, instr(date_added, ' ') - 1) 
    when 'January' then '01'
    when 'February' then '02'
    when 'March' then '03'
    when 'April' then '04'
    when 'May' then '05'
    when 'June' then '06'
    when 'July' then '07'
    when 'August' then '08'
    when 'September' then '09'
    when 'October' then '10'
    when 'November' then '11'
    when 'December' then '12'
  end ||
  substr(date_added, instr(date_added, ' ') + 1, 2) > '20190208'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wKZCo51qaNsmzB5WhwAQ6M/3)

Comment: ok, I can go back and change the dates. Is there a way I can see what is compatible?

Comment: The format you must choose is `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is directly comparable.

Comment: ok, assuming that is the format, how would I convert the string in the column to a date that I can compare it against? That's the part that confuses me

Comment: You don't need to convert, you can do: WHERE date_added > '2019-02-08'

Comment: oooh, I see. If the date is in that format, SQL can understand it "as a date" and not as a string?

Comment: I realize there are two ways to handle the change: 1.) Migrate the DB to add another column with the correct formatting (but I'm using SQLAlchemy and that doesn't sound trivial 2.) Create a new table with a foreign key and the correct format and just do a join, which is what I'll probably do. that will make the lookup easier, I just want to make sure I get the format correct :-)

Comment: No, it is seen as string but a comparable string. Meaning: `2019-02-09` is *greater* than `2019-02-08`

Comment: ahh, makes sense. I saw someone else mention the same thing but without the `-`

Comment: It is the same without `-` and maybe better (if it is 2 bytes less which is maybe the case). But I prefer this format: YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Look, I do not know what database engine you're working with, but in case it's an Sql server, you can do the following:

in the following query it is not necessary to cast the date_added column if it is of the date type, in case it is of the string type, you can also cast it `cast (date_add as date)`.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date_added > cast('2019-01-01' as date)
```

NOTE: it is very important that if they are going to handle dates as string type, they must have a valid format, in Sql Server the dates are saved by default in `yyyy-MM-dd` -`2019-02-10`.

If you want to convert the date in another format you can use the [convert function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)